# Box plot with divisor in Seaborn Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn, boxplot

I m trying to replicate this boxplot with seaborn. I wish to have a division like in the image. I thought that I can create a different Boxplot and union in a single image but isn't a great idea for computation, create many images, use a merge and delete all.

[image]

I used Seaborn to put the value on the box in this way

[image]

this is my function:

```
def boxplot(df, name,prot,min,max):



    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100, 20))
    plt.title(name+ " RMSE from  "+ str(min) +"h PSW to " + str(max) +"h PWS")
    plt.ylabel("RMSE")
    plt.xlabel("")



    box_plot = sns.boxplot(x="Interval" ,y="RMSE", data=df, palette="Set1", showfliers = False)


    ax = box_plot.axes
    lines = ax.get_lines()
    categories = ax.get_xticks()


    for cat in categories:
        # every 4th line at the interval of 6 is median line
        # 0 -> p25 1 -> p75 2 -> lower whisker 3 -> upper whisker 4 -> p50 5 -> upper extreme value
        y = round(lines[4+cat*5].get_ydata()[0],3) 

        ax.text(
            cat, 
            y, 
            f'{y}', 
            ha='center', 
            va='center', 
            fontweight='bold', 
            size=70,
            color='white',
            bbox=dict(facecolor='#445A64'))


    box_plot.figure.tight_layout()


    plt.savefig("output/"+str(prot)+ str(name)+".jpg")

    plt.close(fig)
```

I added this code too for each colour (foolish) to set the same colour for each same elements in the box. Ad example for values "15" on the x-axe I set red, and so on...

for i in range(0,len(box_plot.artists),12):

```
        mybox = ax.artists[i]
        mybox.set_facecolor('red')

    for i in range(1,len(box_plot.artists),12):

        mybox = ax.artists[i]
        mybox.set_facecolor('orange')
```

I tried to use a "hue" for the category in my dataset (adding a row 15,30 near various values) but when use hue the boxplot take so many distances between them like this and I really don't like.

[image]

I tried to use "order" as same but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of plot is called "facetting" when you have a plot that's repeated for different levels of a categorical variable. In seaborn, you can create a `FacetGrid`, or use `catplot` to do this kind of things. With a bit of tweaking, you get a result that's very similar to your desired output

```
# dummy data
N=100
psws = [3,6,12,24,36]
times = [15,30,45,60]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([psws,times], names=['PSW','Time']))
for psw in psws:
    for time in times:
        df[(psw,time)] = np.random.normal(loc=time, size=(N,))
# data need to be in "long-form"
df = df.melt()

g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=df, x='Time', y='value', col='PSW', height=4, aspect=0.5, palette='Greys')
g.fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
# remove the spines of the axes (except the leftmost one)
# and replace with dasehd line
for ax  in g.axes.flatten()[1:]:
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    [tick.set_visible(False) for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()]
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ax.axvline(xmin, ls='--', color='k')
```

[image]